# Composed task doesnt show the actual graph

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have created a composed task on SCDF platform(kubernetes) in my local environment. The composed tasks consisted of multiple individual tasks. When the composed task is viewed in graph mode, it does not show all the tasks. It shows the following instead:

[image]

The task was created using the spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar

Composed task definition

```
task create --name dbsales-pipeline-st --definition "ftp-source-task-st: ftp-source-task --host=ftp-host --username=ftp-user --port=21 --remote-directory='/trial/' --delete-remote-file=true --password=password --source-exchange-name=xml-transform-exchange-source --source-exchange-routing-key=st --name=ftp-source-task-st && xml-transform-source-st: xml-transform-task --sink-exchange-name=xml-transform-exchange-sink --source-queue-name=xml-transform-source-st --sink-exchange-routing-key=st --name=xml-transform-source-st && <ftp-sink-task-aaa: ftp-sink-task --host=ftp-host --username=ftp-user --port=21 --remote-directory='/trial-output/aaa/' --password=password --source-queue-name=xml-transform-sink-st-aaa --name=ftp-sink-task-aaa || ftp-sink-task-bbb: ftp-sink-task --host=ftp-host --username=ftp-user --port=21 --remote-directory='/trial-output/bbb/' --password=password --source-queue-name=xml-transform-sink-st-bbb --name=ftp-sink-task-bbb >"
```

Other version:

- spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes: 1.7.2.RELEASE
- docker:springcloudtask/composedtaskrunner-task:2.1.0.M1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been addressed in [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2763](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2763).

Please upgrade to [v1.7.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#kubernetes-getting-started) K8s-server.